# Python dataframe list-column splitting

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with one of the columns being a list like so:

| RefID | Ref |
| --- | --- |
| Ref1 | (baby, 60, 0) |
| Ref2 | (something, 90, 2) |

I wanted to extract this list as separate fields, as in this code:

```
df['MatchWord'], df['Prox'], df['MatchID'] = df.Ref.str
```

But I get the *"FutureWarning: Columnar iteration..."* error. How else can I split this list-column?

Comment: Is this something that you are looking for?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/split-a-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns

Comment: `Ref` contains strings or a tuple of 3 elements?

Comment: @corralien Three elements

Comment: @Mayur Kr. Garg , no that is for arrays (I forget python terminology) and this is already a list, to I can't use _tolist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.from_records` and `join`:

```
cols = ['MatchWord', 'Prox', 'MatchID']
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['Ref'], index=df.index, columns=cols))
print(out)

# Output
  RefID                 Ref  MatchWord  Prox  MatchID
0  Ref1       (baby, 60, 0)       baby    60        0
1  Ref2  (something, 90, 2)  something    90        2
```

Comment: Nice alternative ;)

Comment: Thanks. This works well, and the both of you have given me some alternatives to play with!

Answer (score 1):

You can `apply(pd.Series)`. This will unpack the items as columns:

```
df['Ref'].apply(pd.Series, index=['MatchWord', 'Prox', 'MatchID'])
```

Or use the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['Ref'].to_list(), columns=['MatchWord', 'Prox', 'MatchID'])
```

Output:

```
   MatchWord  Prox  MatchID
0       baby    60        0
1  something    90        2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. works perfectly